# Booting table-searching-function

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, optimization

I hope my topic is correct placed in this forum.
I have a HTML-Table filled with up to 3000 elements and 5 columns.

For this table and other I wrote a function for filtering the table by its content based on the columns.

More precisely I added an input for each column. The content of the table is then searched live (after pressing a key) by the filter-values from the inputs.

Currently I'm testing the function with a table with up to 2000 elements. The speed is OK, but could be better. I fear a table with 3000 elements or more could be a hard challenge.

I hope to get some ideas/inputs/recommendation from you what I can do to improve my algorithm.

```
//
// Search Table by filter and index
//
// e        -> event
// inputs   -> search-inputs
// idx      -> column-index-array
//
function search_table(e, inputs, idx){
    //get values from search-textbox's
    var values = new Array();
    Array.each(inputs, function(v){ values.push(v.get('value').toString().toUpperCase()); });

    //get table-rows
    var haystack = inputs[0].getParent('table').getChildren('tbody').getChildren('tr')[0];

    var stack = new Array(); //row-stack for recoloring rows
    var hide = 'row_hide';

    //each row
    Array.each(haystack, function(row){
        var childs = row.getChildren('td'); //columns
        var texts = new Array();            //content of cols

        //check idx
        if(idx == null){
            //set index-array from 0 to length
            idx = new Array();
            Array.each(childs, function(v, i){ idx.push(i); });
        }

        //get content from columns based on allowed index
        Array.each(childs, function(child, i){ 
            if(idx.indexOf(i) != -1)
                texts.push(child.get('html').toString().toUpperCase()); 
        });

        //remove css-class for colored row
        row.removeClass('row_0');
        row.removeClass('row_1');

        //check if content matches search-input-values for each column
        var flag = true;
        Array.each(texts, function(text, i){ flag &= text.contains(values[i]);});

        if(flag){
            //add to recoloring stack and 'unhide' row
            stack.push(row);
            row.removeClass(hide);
        } else {
            //hide if not matching
            row.addClass(hide);
        }           
    });

    //recolor matching rows
    Array.each(stack, function(row, i){
        row.addClass('row_' + (i % 2));
    });
}
```

Kind Regards
Mario

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK thanks. Can someone move it or do I have to repost it there?